# gcloud get-logs command not working

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I was trying to download logs from a GAE app using the gcloud cli

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud-app#Downloading_logs) the command I was supposed to use was:

```
gcloud preview app get-logs --version 1 default mylogs.txt
```

However, when running this command I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app) Invalid choice: 'get-logs'. Did you mean 'deploy'?
```

All the tools are installed and there's nothing to update using `gcloud components list` and `gcloud components update`

Also I have authenticated and set the project

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project mytestproject
```

Comment: Documentation link is dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command moved to go underneath the modules command group, and unfortunately the documentation lagged behind.

The equivalent command is

> $ gcloud preview app modules get-logs --version 1 default mylogs.txt

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks. But Google documentation took me 100 reputation points :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **appcfg.py request_logs myapp/ mylogs.txt** to download the logs for your application which is running in App Engine.

This Command only works for App Engine but not for Managed VM's.Refer to the link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_logs

Comment: As you said it's Python only so it doesn't help.